# GWT: Problems using TextBox.selectAll() on "onFocus event" in Chrome

Tags: java, gwt

In GWT, I'm using TextBox.selectAll() in a TextBox widget - which is triggered from a OnFocus event.

This works fine in FireFox, but in chrome it quickly selects the text and then deselects it again. 
I'm guessing that another event is being triggered, forcing the textbox to deselect the text.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: I have the same issue, but in IE; it works in Chrome; actually in Chrome I don't even need the selectAll(), it does it automatically; I tried the solution below for IE and it didn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try calling `selectAll()` from a [`Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29).  It's possible that the focus event is being received before the normal caret-position update is handled by the UI.